# How to protect api plateform operations with privileges

Tags: php, symfony, roles, api-platform.com

I have an api plateform project (symfony) that contain an entity User with column Roles(array), I have 3 ROLES: ROLE_USER, ROLE_COMMERCIAL, ROLE_ADMIN, I am protecting my operations likes this:

```php
"get"={
     "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
     "security_post_denormalize_message"="Sorry, Only admins can View Users List"
}
```

But What I would to achieve is to give each user privileges like for example a user can view users list but cannot edit it , I want to edit the privileges for each user later that's why I don't want to use the role column. I think of this tables structure :

- User(id,user_name,role_id)
- Role(role_id,role_name)
- Privilege(id,priv_name, role_id)

Answer (score 1):

you checkout voters (https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/voters.html) . It won't be exactly like you wanted , but it's the easiest way to give privileges, in your case to allow a user to view a list but not to edit it.